# Eisenbud's Proof of the Cohen Structure Theorem

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I'm currently reading through the proof of the (equicharacteristic) Cohen Structure Theorem as given in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*.

He proves a theorem (Theorem 7.8) which allows us to find a coefficient field (a field isomorphic to the residue field $K$) in any complete local Noetherian ring $R$, provided it contains a field $k$.

This theorem relies on $K/k$ being a separable extension (where here $k$ is viewed as its image in $K$). His justification is as follows: if $R$ contains a field, then if it has characteristic $0$ it contains $\mathbb{Q}$, or if it has characteristic $p$ it contains $\mathbb{F}_p$. Both of these fields are perfect. He then asserts after the statement of Theorem 7.8 that every extension of a perfect field is separable, which allows us to apply the theorem to any complete local Noetherian ring containing a field.

However, as far as I am aware, only algebraic extensions of perfect fields need be separable. I have been trying to show that the extensions $K/\mathbb{Q}$ and $K/\mathbb{F}_p$ are algebraic, but cannot seem to find a justification. The Noetherian criterion doesn't appear to be much use here since the ideals are trivial, and that is the only condition I can't see an obvious use for in his proof.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Many books explain this, so here is the idea. If $k\subset K$ is a field extension, one considers $\Omega^1_{K/k}$, the module of differentials. This is a $K$-vector space and generated by elements of the form $dx,x\in K$. Thus, you can find a basis of the form $\{dx_i|i\in I\}$. If $k$ is perfect, one shows that the $x_i$s are algebraically independent over $k$ and the extension $k(x_i|i\in I)\subset K$ is algebraic and separable.

Comment: Thank you Mohan, he did mention differentials in the build up to that theorem, so I'll be sure to read his chapter on those. Would you by any chance happen to have a reference for a proof of the result you mention? I can't seem to find one in Eisenbud's book

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is unsure about the terminology specifically in Eisenbud's proof, I realise now that he was referring to a more general definition of separability which applies to transcendental extensions.

He defines this in section A1.2 and proves that, using this notion of separability, every extension of a perfect field is separable.